# Selectively disabling automatic table updates (dbCreate="none") on domain class/table level in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In Grails, is it possible to disable automatic table creation/updates for one domain class only?

Let's say I have domain classes `Foo`, `Bar` and `Zonk`. I want automatic table updates for `Foo` and `Bar`, whereas I want no automatic changes at all made to the `Zonk` table.

**Is that possible?**

Why the need to selectively disable table updates? One such case is when the table behind `Zonk` contains millions of rows, so that any change made to that table (such as adding a reference to a foreign key) would take days to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct support but you could hack in a fix. But you really don't even want automatic updates for the "safe" tables. A few examples - if you rename a column or table, it'll add a new one but not delete the old one. If you add a new column that shouldn't allow nulls, it'll be added as nullable since otherwise old rows won't be valid. And if you widen a column it won't be updated even though there would be no data loss.

You'd be much better off using database migrations, and Liquibase is the best option currently. The [Database Migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) is the official migrations plugin for Grails and uses Liqibase.